# Is there a snip equivalent on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, screenshot

I use snip all the time on windows for taking screenshots.

Is there something similar in raspbian?

**Note**: I wish to take screenshots in the raspbian desktop environment, (LXDE).

My desktop details are as follows:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg --get-selections | grep desktop
desktop-base                                    install
desktop-file-utils                              install
gir1.2-freedesktop:armhf                        install
gnome-desktop3-data                             install
gsettings-desktop-schemas                       install
libgnome-desktop-3-10                           install
```

The linux standard base is as follows:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Raspbian
    Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
    Release:        8.0
    Codename:       jessie
```

Comment: From what environment?  GUI or text screen?

Comment: From the raspbian desktop environment, the following packages are installed : desktop-base                                    install
desktop-file-utils                              install
gir1.2-freedesktop:armhf                        install
gnome-desktop3-data                             install
gsettings-desktop-schemas                       install
libgnome-desktop-3-10                           install

Comment: @joan I'm using Raspbian GNU/ Linux (jessie) **Release : 8.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The raspbian desktop environment" is actually [LXDE](http://lxde.org/), so you might want to investigate that way.

If nothing turns up, as a last resort [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) will take screenshots and should be available via `apt`. It is a bit of a sledgehammer in this context:

- Open it on a separate desktop (I think having multiple desktops is unfamiliar to most MS Windows users?).
- Select *File->Create->Screenshot*, there are further self-explanatory options there.
- Switch back to the desktop you want a snap of and click the mouse.
- To save the image, use *File->Export As*; GIMP's native format is viewable only in GIMP.

GIMP is fairly versatile and, as the homepage says, now in its 20th year, so if you look around there may be a way to do this via a command or script you could associate with a hotkey in LXDE.

---

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php) provides a simpler method (`apt install imagemagick` first), e.g.:

```
import -window root screenshot.jpg
```

Again, this could be associated with a hotkey or something.  You can do it from another desktop terminal by using a brief pause:

```
sleep 3; import -window root screenshot.jpg
```

Then switch over to wherever.

Comment: I've added a simpler option than GIMP at the bottom ;)

Answer (score 0):

To add a screenshot tool as a hotkey, these [instructions](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_take_screenshots) detail how to:

1. set up a tool (personally, I recommend *scrot*, as you can get it to set the file name to include the date and time)
2. edit `~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml` (NB: different for a Raspberry Pi than the instructions) to include something like this in the <keyboard> section:

   ```
   <keybind key="Print">
    <action name="Execute">
     <command>scrot 'screenshot-%F_%T.png'</command>
    </action>
   </keybind>
   ```
3. Reload your preferences with `openbox --reconfigure`

This should save a screen shot if you hit PrintScreen.